# I'm interested in the examples of "to dream something"

Tags: meaning

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dream_2):
a definition:
to dream — [intransitive, transitive] to experience a series of images, events and feelings in your mind while you are asleep
an example:
to dream something: **(1)** *Did it really happen or did I just dream it*?

I made up some sentences similar to (1):
**(2)** *I dreamed my friends*.
**(3)** *I dreamed my house*.
**(4)** *I dreamed my dog*.

Are (2), (3) and (4) correct?
If not, then why not?

---

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dream_2):
a definition:
to dream — [intransitive, transitive] to imagine and think about something that you would like to happen
an example:
to dream something: **(5)** *Who'd have dreamt it? They're getting married*.

I made up some sentences similar to (5):
**(6)** *I dreamed a good job*.
**(7)** *I dreamed a big salary*.

Are (6) and (7) correct?
If not, then why not?

Comment: When describing a dream experienced during sleep, we talk about something that happened, usually with a complete sentence, e.g. I dreamed that I was naked in front of the whole school, that I was a rich man, that my dog could speak, that I was being chased by giant toads. Thus none of your examples would be natural.

Comment: Oxford Learners' Dictionary actually gives examples of the correct usage - _I dreamed about X_ or _I dreamed of X_.

Comment: @KateBunting But my question is about "_to dream X_". It has nothing to do with "_to dream about/of X_".

Comment: As James says, the only direct object we can use with _dream_ is _it_ or a clause _that [something happened]_.

Answer (score 1):

All of 2-7 are non-idiomatic.

The object of "dream" should be a content clause "I dreamed that my friend were with me".  Or an "about PP":  "I dreamed about my friends".

The "did you dream it" is an idiom, and doesn't generalise.